# ASP.NET MVC 4 Application on IIS 8 not showing png images

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-8

I deployed asp.net mvc 4 application on windows 2012 server today. Everything is working fine but no png images are loading.

The below are the screenshots

[image: When Accessed through webserver]

[image: When Accessed on localhost]

These are some things I checked

I can load different images in this folder except the ".png"s.

Static Content was installed on my webserver. 
[image: Static Content ticked on server]

Check MIME types .. png are included there

Added the following code to route config

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.png")
```

Also checked the advanced Attributes by going into the properties of the file on webserver. The below is the screenshot.

[image: Advance Attributes of file]

Comment: What is the path to your PNG file? I notice you are running in a virtual directory in one case and root in the local host case.

Comment: On server : http://192.168.250.201/NextGen/Content/logo.png    LocalHost : http://localhost:55986/Content/logo.png

Comment: show image's html code

Comment: Maybe you are wrong URL because of relative path

Comment: @majidgeek The below is the code .. which is same in both cases ...<img src="~/Content/logo.jpg" height="60" width="160" class="navbar-brand" />

Comment: right click on image in two different server and check images URL,it must be same,is it?

Answer (score 1):

Try use this:

```
<img src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/logo.png")%>" alt=""/>
```

Comment: I done a fresh deployment from scratch it worked. Thanks anyway.